# Strange memory address resulting in BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to wrap my head around a strange problem in my iPad app. It's a pretty simple app, only one root view controller with a little board game inside.

Sometimes, seemingly at random, the app freezes and I get a BAD_ACESS on a delegate reference I use in one of my classes. I've been solving BAD_ACCESS-problems for a long time, but this is very strange. The object the delegate is referring to is the root view controller, and that should never b released. I put a log line in the -(void)dealloc method and that never occurs. I even tried to over retain the object but it still disappears.

Even if I run the app in the profiler with NSZombie detection on, the profiler just stops when this happens. Doesn't show any results whatsoever.

Another strange thing I noticed was the memory address. If I log it like NSLog(@"%p", delegate); i get "0x1" as a result. A nil pointer is 0x0 so testing for if(delegate) does return true even though the object has vanished. And even if the object itself was deallocated, the memory address would still be intact?

The problem only occurs after some use, between like 15 and 45 sec.

Doed someone know how to tackle this problem? I'd be greatly thankful.

This is how the delegate is assigned. The _delegate is the root view controller which is always active.

```
-(id)initWithDelegate:(NSObject <TheGameDelegate>*)_delegate level:(int)_level;
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        delegate = [_delegate retain];
        ...
```

Here is where it crashes:

```
-(void)countdown:(NSTimer*)timer;
{
    time -= 1;
    if(delegate) // this is always true
    {
        NSLog(@"%p", delegate); // this prints a normal memory address until right before crash when it prints "0x1"
        [delegate theGameTick:self]; // accessing deleagte gives BAD_ACCESS
    }
    ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what else is happening but can you try [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(theGameTick:) withObject:self] ?

Comment: Same result :/ It is the delegate that is broken so no matter what method i call I should get the same error. Maybe it is the parent method (countdown) that should be called on the main thread?

Comment: somewhere you overwrite delegate. it's impossible to debug this without the code.

Comment: I can assure that is not the case. I've done a project search on "delegate =" and found nothing but "delegate = [_delegate retain];". Besides, I don't even know how to set a variable to 0x1. And even if i overwrite it, it shouldn't get bad_acces, it should try to send the call to a different object.

Comment: you don't know how to set `foo = 1`? no offense, but that doesn't give me trust in you  knowing how to check for that sort of thing… and yes, it _should_ give you BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: are you using @property for your delegate, check your setDelegate: method also. Find another way to access your rootViewController directly, such as, `self.navigationController.rootViewController` or use class method `sharedRootView`, then log out both objects when it crashes.

Comment: I think we will have to look at code. And true, you should never retain the delegate (to avoid retain cycles). 
Also are you returning self at the end of initWithDelegate: ? I made this mistake once and the application worked but with crashes in future...it messes up with memory.

Comment: hop: The compiler would give a warning if you try to assign an integer to pointer :) The problem was a broken loop that accessed an array of ints (int arr[x];) with index -1 (arr[-1] = 1). Apparently that made it point to my delegate variable, thus setting its value to 1. I didn't even know that was possible :O

Answer (score 0):

imo, your delegate implementation is weird.Retaining delegates is not the good idea.
 
Try adding to the header:
`@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate` and then the method would look like

`-(id)initWithDelegate:(id)_delegate level:(int)_level;
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil)
    {
        self.delegate = _delegate;
...}`
 
 
as well as in further methods you reference to self.delegate.
(you can add the required protocol as well, i skipped it for clearer code)

Comment: Hmm, but what if the delegate gets released by another object, the object would dealloc but I have a broken reference. Retaining the delegate and releasing upon dealloc solves that problem. If you use an object, you should make sure it doesn't get dealloced by someone else, right?

Comment: but if you have the delegate retaining the object and the object retaining the delegate neither will be deallocated(because it is still referenced somewhere). This is called retain cycle. That's why you should not retain nor release delegates. The case Whether delegate has been released or not is ht matter of proper object ownership policy.

Comment: well, that sounds about right :) i will no longer retain my delegates!